# Bring view to front of image view - Android XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am having a couple of issue with the layout on one of my activities. Here is what I currently have:

[image]

As you can see, the green circle is underneath the header image, even though it should overlap at the top. Also, as you can just see, the text to the right of the circle is underneath the header image even though it should be on a single line underneath.

This is my current XML (I've excluded the irrelevant stuff):

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="135dp"
            android:id="@+id/headerImageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="@drawable/header_image_test" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="49dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/headerImageView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/headerImageView"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/star"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/headerImageView"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/main_details_layout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/waitTimeTextView"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:text="@string/wait_time_default"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/color0"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:text="Attraction Name"
                    android:textSize="23dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:id="@+id/attractionNameTextView"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Last Updated"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:id="@+id/updatedTextView"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

For the text, I have tried forcing the number of lines to be 1, and specifically setting the height, but neither seems to have worked. Also, for the circle I have tried brining it to the front in code, but it messes up the layout.

Anyone have any suggestions for changes?

Comment: can you try by giving top margin equal to image height for checking?

Comment: also remove negative margin from textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Layout is wrong. Try This:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:id="@+id/headerImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:background="@drawable/header_image_test" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/headerImageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/headerImageView"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/star"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/headerImageView"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
        android:id="@+id/main_details_layout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/waitTimeTextView"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="@string/wait_time_default"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/color0"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:text="Attraction Name"
                android:textSize="23dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:lines="1"
                android:id="@+id/attractionNameTextView"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Last Updated"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:id="@+id/updatedTextView"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That fixes the issue with the circle, however the text is still underneath the image if it is longer than 1 line. Any ideas? I'm not sure why settings 'lines' to 'maxLines' to 1 doesn't work.

Comment: @VivekMishra OP wants it over the header image.

Comment: @user3746428 try adding android:singleLine="true" to your textview you wanted to be single line

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. And yes, @oguzhand, I need the circle to be overlapping the header image.